# Neo4J multiple unwinds unexpected behavior

Tags: node.js, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I am trying to execute the following Neo4J query.

```
CREATE (c:Content)
WITH c
UNWIND $resources as resource
    MATCH (p:Person {userId: resource["userId"]})
    CREATE (r:Resource)
    CREATE (p)-[:CREATES]->(r)
    CREATE (c)-[:CONTAINS]->(r)
WITH c
UNWIND $tags as tag
    MATCH (t:Tag {name: tag})
    CREATE (c)-[:IS]->(t)
WITH c
UNWIND $goalCategories as category
    MATCH (atc:ATCategory {name: category})
    CREATE (c)-[:IS]->(atc)
```

$resources is an object list and $tags and $categories are list of strings. I have left the data manipulation part for simplicity.

When this query executes, it creates multiple relationships between c and atc which means that it repeats the category for each item in the tags. To my knowledge, since c is singular, the WITH c block should close the previous unwind but this does not happen. What's weird is that, this does not happen for the resources unwind.

Shortly, the code threats like the **UNWIND $goalCategories as category** is inside the **UNWIND $tags as tag** part. If the same happened between **UNWIND $resources as resource** and **UNWIND $tags as tag**, it would make sense, but I couldn't figure out why this is only happening for the latter part and not the prior part.

I would really appreciate the help.

Btw: I am executing the code with neo4j-driver on nodejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running multiple consecutive `UNWIND` statements will lead to cartesian products. Essentially, all the nested `UNWIND` will be executed x times, where the x is the number of rows from the previous unwind. The `WITH c` does not close the previous `UNWIND` statement, you need to add any aggregation function. For example, you could use the `count()` aggregation function to effectively reduce the count of rows in between consecutive `UNWIND` statements to 1 (or close a previous `UNWIND` as you state).

```
CREATE (c:Content)
WITH c
UNWIND $resources as resource
    MATCH (p:Person {userId: resource["userId"]})
    CREATE (r:Resource)
    CREATE (p)-[:CREATES]->(r)
    CREATE (c)-[:CONTAINS]->(r)
WITH c, count(*) as dummy
UNWIND $tags as tag
    MATCH (t:Tag {name: tag})
    CREATE (c)-[:IS]->(t)
WITH c, count(*) AS dummy
UNWIND $goalCategories as category
    MATCH (atc:ATCategory {name: category})
    CREATE (c)-[:IS]->(atc)
```